# Deploy Azure Industrial-IOT Stuck at Log In

Tags: azure, iot

I am attempting to deploy the Azure Industrial IoT Platform and Simulation in Azure using the deployment scripts found at this [Github](https://azure.github.io/Industrial-IoT/deploy/howto-deploy-all-in-one.html).

I clone the repo then .\deploy and it starts. It then installs Az and AzureAD. It then just says Signing in ....
It has been on this screen for over two hours.

I have actually been trying this all day with no luck but have restarted it a few times.

I am a global admin in AAD.

Does this mean I have tenant wide consent for my application?

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Let it run over nite. When I arrived today I had message
Warning '***' contains more than one active subscription. First one will be selected for further use.
Followed by
Please choose a subscription from this list
then my two subscriptions.

Its running and building now.